# Combination of 1981 glide reflections in $\mathbb{E}^2$ still a glide reflection?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, isometry

I was wondering if the combination of 1981 glide reflections over different lines is still a glide reflection over a line in $\mathbb{E}^2$ (so every glide reflection can be over a different line). Or may there be only limited cases in which this is true?

A glide reflection is a combination of a translation along a line $S$ and a reflection over a line $S$. We can see it as:
$$S_b: \mathbb{E}^2 \to \mathbb{E}^2: x \mapsto S_b(x) = x + 2\overrightarrow{x\pi_s(x)} + b  $$
Here is $\pi_s(x)$ the intersectionpoint of the orthogonal projection on the mirrorline $S$ and $S$ itself. $b$ has the direction alongside $S$.

Comment: Every orientation-reversing isometry of the plane is either a pure reflection or a glide reflection.

Comment: And is the combination of orientation-reversing isometries still an orientation-reversing isometry?

Comment: THe combination of an odd number of them is!

Comment: A composition of two orientation-*reversing* maps is orientation-*preserving*, and composition of an orientation-*reversing* and an orientation-*preserving* map is orientation-*reversing*.

Comment: @Wojowu this has gotten to the point where it's now worthy of an answer!

Comment: @Wojowu thanks, I see how this leads to an intuitive solution, but is there any formal prove for your statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that every isometry is one of the following:

- the identity map,
- a rotation,
- a translation,
- a reflection,
- a glide reflection.

(if we allow degenerate cases, those classes overlap, but it doesn't matter)

Let me make the following ad-hoc definition: an isometry is *orientation-preserving* if it is the identity, a rotation or a translation, and it is *orientation-reversing* if it is a reflection or a glide reflection. We then have the following three results, which are relatively easy to verify case-by-case:

- A composition of two orientation-preserving isometries is orientation-preserving,
- A composition of two orientation-reverving isometries is orientation-preserving,
- A composition of an orientation-preserving isometry and an orientation-reverving isometry is orientation-reversing.

It is easy to deduce from those facts that a composition of an odd number of orientation-reversing is orientation-reversing (and of an even number is orientation-preserving). Therefore, a composition of 1981 glide reflections is still a glide reflection (or a pure reflection).

---

Now, let me just say that if you are willing to accept some linear algebra, then you can make all of the above less ad-hoc. Every isometry is an *affine transformation*, which means that it can be written as a composition of a translation and some invertible linear transformation. Let me denote the latter by $T(A)$ for an isometry $A$. A less ad-hoc definition is as follows: we call $A$ *orientation-preserving* if $\det T(A)>0$ and *orientation-reversing* if $\det T(A)<0$.

It's not hard to check that $T(A\circ B)=T(A)\circ T(B)$, therefore
$$\det T(A\circ B)=\det(T(A)\circ T(B))=\det T(A)\cdot\det T(B).$$
From this it's very easy to deduce an odd number of orientation-reversing maps compose to an orientation-reversing map, and now we are done once we check that glide reflections are orientation-reversing (straightforward) and vice versa (less obvious, requires classification of isometries).